# Twitter Bootstrap - nav bar not rendering on Firefox and Safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for the toolbar:

```
  <div class='navbar navbar-fixed-top'>
    <div class='navbar-inner'>
      <div class='container'>
        <a class='btn btn-navbar' data-target='.nav-collapse' data-toggle='collapse'>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </a>
        <div class='nav-collapse'>
          <ul class='nav'>
            <li class='active'>
              <a href='some_url'>My Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='some_url'>Option 1 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='some_url'>Another option</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='some_url'>Another option</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It works ok on Chrome, but on Firefox and Safari the toolbar doesn't render.  Any idea why it wouldn't render?

THanks!

Comment: Can you post a link to your site or recreate your issue over at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to take a look? Your setup should work (aside from the single quotes, which just looks strange but should work regardless).

Comment: It works in my safari in default bootstrap sample with navbar replaced with yours.